# Getting rid of random syntax highlighting

Tags: eclipse, javascript, syntax-highlighting

I'm having a problem with Eclipse. It randomly highlights code in grey, usually as I type something. It doesn't always appear when I type, and goes away at random times too. It's really annoying. I can't seem to figure out what the color is attached to in preferences Either.

I have the Web package installed. Here's an example of the highlighting:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The highlighting you're seeing here is related to variable instances. You can disable its color highlighting from the preferences screen as a permanent solution, but I discourage that as highlighting instances is invaluable!

Instead, you can fairly easily resolve this each time by placing your caret on a different variable. It may require an intermediate save.

I've seen this sort of odd behavior fairly rarely; perhaps you should also make sure you're using recent version of Eclipse.